# failing to load jquery

Tags: jquery, moodle

I am trying to load code in Moodle through jQuery I get the following error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

What am I doing wrong?

```html
<h1 id="ciao">
  <?php echo $COURSE->fullname ?>
</h1>

<a id="marko" href="report2.php">PDF</a>
<form action="manage.php" method="POST">
  <select name="ciao">
    <?php foreach ($result as $key => $res) { ?>
      <option id="search" value="search" name="search">
        <?php echo $res->uename ?>
      </option>
    <?php } ?>
  </select>
</form>
```

```js
               function init() {
                  var search = $('#search').text();
                  search.click(function() {
                        // $.ajax({
                            //     type: 'post',
                            //     url: 'manage.php',
                            //     data: {
                            //         source1: "some text",
                            //         source2: "some text 2"
                            //     },
                            //     success: function( data ) {
                            //         console.log( data );
                            //     }
                            // });
                            console.log('ok);
                            });
                           }
```

$(document).ready(init);

Comment: The code you've shown does not produce the error. It must be coming from somewhere else in your logic.

Comment: Given your edit, the problem there is a syntax error because you're missing a closing `'` in the `console.log()`

Comment: no It has to do with click method

Comment: Yes, in THE click method, as Rory mentioned, there is a missing `'` after `ok` ... check your example. You have `console.log('ok);` which is missing the closing single quote after ok.